# How to add functions in R

Tags: r, functional-programming, addition

I am trying to sum the functions in a list to create a new function.  This is easy for a small number of functions.  Here is an example:

```
f <- function(x){x}
g <- function(x){x+1}
```

Now we sum `f` and `g`.

```
fg <- function(x){f(x) + g(x)}
```

But if I have 100 functions that I want to sum, this method becomes clumsy.  Is there a way to create a function like `fg` above automatically from a list?

Comment: MrFlick's answer is good, but you really should ask yourself why/how you ended up with an overflowing-stack (sorry :-) ) of independent little functions in the first place.  I can't imagine there's much meaning to the sum of 100 unrelated functions.  Maybe you can write some recursive function which does all of them in one?

Comment: @Carl Your intuition is correct--they are not unrelated functions.  I'm not sure I understand your suggestion regarding recursion.  Instead of defining separate functions for something like x+0*a, x+1*a,... and summing them up, you're suggesting I find away to make the function x+0*a + x+1*a +... using some sort of recursion, right off the bat?  If so, do you know how to do that?

Comment: You just have coefficients for a vector values? It looks like you can just do that with simple matrix algebra.

Comment: @MrFlick No, I actually have complicated expressions within error functions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sapply` to loop over the functions and apply then

```
f <- function(x){x}
g <- function(x){x+1}
h <- function(x){x*2}

funs<-list(f,g,h)

x <- 2
rowSums(matrix(sapply(funs, function(f, z) f(z), z=x), nrow=length(x)))
# [1] 9
```

I use the `matrix` and `rowSums` functions just in case you want to be able to call it when `x` is a vector of values as well

```
x <- 1:3
rowSums(matrix(sapply(funs, function(f, z) f(z), z=x), nrow=length(x)))
# [1]  5  9 13
```

You can make it cleaner by making a helper function

```
getfunsum <- function(funs) {
    force(funs)
    function(x) {
        rowSums(matrix(sapply(funs, function(f, z) f(z), z=x), nrow=length(x)))
    }
}
fgh <- getfunsum(funs)
fgh(1:3)
# [1]  5  9 13
```

Answer (score 4):

I prefer `Reduce`:

```
f <- function(x){x}
g <- function(x){x+1}
h <- function(x){x*2}

funs<-list(f,g,h)

x <- 1:3

Reduce("+", lapply(funs, function(f, y) f(y), y=x))
#[1]  5  9 13
```

Of course, the return values of all functions must have the same length.

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
 fun1 <- function(i,a) {
                eval(substitute(function(x, a) {x+i*a}, list(i=i)))}

n <- 0:3
lst <- lapply(n, fun1)
rowSums(sapply(lst, function(f) f(12:14, 3)))
#[1] 66 70 74
```